# Django: any way to execute consecutive model.save() operations as 1 single DB request?

Tags: python, django, database

I have a function that does operations on a Django model instance, and I'm trying to break it up into sub operations that can be used independently. However, this means that I end up calling `.save` on each change and trigger a DB request.

```
def subop1(instance):
    instance.a1 = 1
    instance.save()

def subop1(instance):
    instance.a2 = 2
    instance.save()

def subop1(instance):
    instance.a3 = 3
    instance.save()

def main_op(instance):
    subop1(instance) # triggers 1 DB request
    subop2(instance) # triggers 1 DB request
    subop3(instance) # triggers 1 DB request
```

Is there any way to avoid having `.save` triggering a DB request every time while still keeping each function independently functional? Maybe some way of deferring the `.save` operations until some context manager exits and then saving all at once with 1 DB request.

Tried to read through `transaction` documentation but I didn't find anything that fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could you add an optional argument to your methods, for example:

```
def subop1(instance, commit=True):
    instance.a1 = 1
    if commit:
        instance.save()
```

Then call your instances with `commit=False`, and then call `save()` manually.

```
def main_op(instance):
    subop1(instance, commit=False)
    subop2(instance, commit=False)
    subop3(instance, commit=False)
    instance.save()
```

Comment: This works, fairly simply. I was wondering if there was a more Django-esk way to do it. Will wait a little bit but will accept this if nothing better comes along since it generalizes and is indeed elegant.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

The instance is the same so you can do this:

```
def subop1(instance):
    instance.a1 = 1

def subop1(instance):
    instance.a2 = 2

def subop1(instance):
    instance.a3 = 3

def main_op(instance):
    subop1(instance)
    subop2(instance)
    subop3(instance) 
    instance.save() # triggers 1 DB request
```

You can do this because instance is an object and it is passed by refence and not by value.

So, if you edit an instance in a function, the changes also remain outside that method

**Method 2:**

Or you can do something like this:

```
from threading import Timer

class Object():
    a1 = 0
    a2 = 0
    a3 = 0

    def save(self):
        print(self.a1)
        print(self.a2)
        print(self.a3)        

def subop1(instance):
    instance.a1 = 1
    restart_timer(instance)

def subop2(instance):
    instance.a2 = 2
    restart_timer(instance)


def subop3(instance):
    instance.a3 = 3
    restart_timer(instance)


def main_op(instance):
    subop1(instance)
    subop2(instance)
    subop3(instance)

timer = None

def restart_timer(instance):
    global timer
    if timer != None:
        timer.cancel() # this delete last timer
    timer = Timer(5.0, Object.save, [instance]) # This call the save method after 5 sec
    timer.start() # This start the new timer

if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = Object()
    main_op(obj)
```

**Pay attention** however that this is not the best way to do it because the garbage collector could eliminate the instance so use this method only if you are sure that the object will remain global all the time.

Otherwise you have to add this method to the object class.

```
def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
    self.save()
```

**Pay attention pt.2** 
In this case, your item will be saved whenever you dispose of it.
So if you don't voluntarily save the object, it'll be saved anyway.

**So the best method in the end is to do more transactions on the database.**

Comment: the reason this doesn't quite do it is because I want to be able to use them independently of the calling function. So they should be able to save if needed.

Comment: Hi Davide, I appreciate the extra work for the different alternatives. I'd opt to avoid global timers since this will be shared by multiple concurrent requests and could create concurrency issues (e.g. each thread canceling the other one's timer)

Answer (score 0):

You can do in the following manner.

```
def subop1(instance):
instance.a1 = 1

def subop1(instance):
instance.a2 = 2

def subop1(instance):
instance.a3 = 3

def main_op(instance):
subop1(instance)
subop2(instance)
subop3(instance) 
instance.save()
```

Comment: the reason this doesn't quite do it is because I want to be able to use them independently of the calling function. So they should be able to save if needed.